# Unable to run the code while using LibGit2sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, libgit2sharp

I am facing a problem working with LibGit2Sharp, I have to fix some issues in my code that I can do only when I would be able to debug the code but when I am running the application in debug mode and trying to access the repository

I am getting an error common language runtime detected an invalid program

```
            try
            {
                using (var repo = new Repository(path))
                {
                    // some other code
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log the error
            }
```

I am unable to debug the code because on first line only getting error.

could you please help me to solve this issue so I can fix some other issues.
published code is working properly in dev environment, so now only thing I am doing is logging the maximum things in log and after doing the changes trying to deploy the DLL to dev and run the application then analyzing the log.

its eating my head, please I tried maximum solutions which are posted in google or stack overflow but no luck.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying it works on one machine but not on your machine or that it works on your machine when running without debugging but fails when debugging. As I understand it, libgit2sharp is a dotnet wrapper library and requires native dlls which will be different depending on whether your app is 64-bit or 32-bit. So you could get this error if for example you have a 32-bit native dll, but your app is 64-bit or vice-versa.

Comment: It is working in server, where application is hosted but there are some issues when files are getting commit etc so  I want to debug the issue locally but I am getting error common language runtime detected an invalid program. I already tried these ways like enabling 32 bit, uncheck code optimize. I have tagged LibGit2Sharp so I am expecting some solution from their end.